# Does python load libraries already imported when the same library is in an imported module?

Tags: python

Say I have the following script

```py
#module1
import some_heavy_module

def main1():
    pass

if __name__=="__main__":
    main1()
```

and I import that script in another module which also uses `heavy_module`

```py
#main.py
import some_heavy_module
from submodule import main1

some_heavy_module.do_stuff()
a = main1()
```

does python import `some_heavy_module` both in the `main.py` and when `module1` is imported, or does it in `module1` use the already imported `some_heavy_module` from `main`?

Comment: You should be able to easily see what happens by adding print statements to a dummy import. And read about `sys.modules` [here](https://realpython.com/python-import/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within each python process, modules are only imported once (unless you manually force things to be loaded again via `reload` or similar). Modules are [cached in `sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache).

You can manually validate this by adding a print to the top of two modules where one imports the other, then import them both from another module.